# Python- in need of help to simplify my code

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

So i have a list and a for loop (still a beginner sorry) and i want this code but in a more simplified way and without a new backwards list. ^The edit

```
lyrics = [["First", "and a partride in a pear tree",], ["second", "2 things"], ["Third", "3 things"], ["Fourth", "4 things"], ["Fifth", "5 things"], ["Sixth", "six things"], ["Seven", "7 things"], ["Eigth", "8 things"], ["Nineth", "nine things"], ["tenth", "Ten things"], ["eleventh", "eleven things"], ["Twelveth", "twelve things"]]

backwards = []

for i in range(12):
    print("On the", lyrics[i][0], "my true love gave to me,               lyrics[i][1])
backwards.append(lyrics[i][1])
for each in backwards:
    print (each) #Forgot how i did it in the reverse order but i want this in a more simplified version to learn from.
```

PS: Would like as few lines as possible (im able to do it in 8 lines but would like at least 3-4) :/

Comment: Can you show us how you've achieved this in 8 lines?

Comment: Managed to do it in school but i stored each index within another list and then printed the list line by line :/

Comment: You may even achieve it in one line. Show us what you tried and your desired output. We will provide the best way to achieve it. That's how Magic works on SO :)

Comment: Ok il re-do my 8 lined version.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri, How do you do it in one line? (Just curious; unless you mean you can put the `for` loop header and print on the same line).

Comment: @DYZ: `print '\n'.join(my_list + my_list[::-1])` where `my_list` is the variable holding these values

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Ok i've added it to my post.

Comment: @Envurb: I am not clear about the expected output. Can please mention what you desire as the desired result

Comment: @Moinuddin Quadri The same result but in a more simplified way to make it more efficient. with a printing function that prints everything before that loop index

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Nope, your "one-liner" prints something else:A,B,C,C,B,A each on its own line.

Comment: @DYZ: I didn't understand the question on first place, check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40951468/2063361) with one-liner :)

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Oh, ok.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use `list` for your variables: it's a built-in function.

Second, print slices:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    print(list(reversed(l[:i+1])))
```

Comment: `print(reversed(l[:i+1]))` may be.

Comment: Hi ive read up about slices, can you elaborate on them? going to try to use your improvement now.

Comment: `reversed` returns an iterator on python 3: output is `<list_reverseiterator object at 0x0000000003D8B240>
<list_reverseiterator object at 0x0000000003D8B240>
<list_reverseiterator object at 0x0000000003D8B240>`. to get a list do `print(l[:i+1][::-1])`

Comment: @Envurb Here's a good explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation

Comment: Right, added list() to the example.

Comment: Doesnt seem to work, what i'm trying to do is a challenge i set myself, but since i don't fully python it's a bit tricky. im trying to code the 12 days of christmas song lol. Il try the edited reversed version now.

Comment: It printed with the square brackets. the reversed version brings up an error: 'list' object was not callable

Comment: Do you use Python 2 or Python 3? To remove brackets, use function `.join()`.

Comment: @Envurb, `list object is not callable` is exactly because you ruined the built-in function `list()`. You need to restart your Python development environment and give your list another name.

Comment: Ok it worked however, im using a 2d list. Is there a way to print the second index of the index without the square brackets?

Comment: @Envurb, This sounds like a different problem to me.

Comment: @DYZ Check the post again, ive included my code. Im trying to basically simplify it to 4 or less lines.

Comment: @DYZ sorry i went off course. Was wanting a printing function to print everything in the list on that loop index which corresponds to the list. Just like the answer you gave me, but is there a way to do this with a 2d list and only print the second index of that index on a new line?

Comment: @Envurb I am still not sure what you want. Give an example of desired output.

Comment: @DYZ  output: First day) 1 thing \n second day) 2 things 1 thing \n third day) 3 things, 2 things, 1 thing. #Where the 'day' and 'things' are stored in a 2d list

Comment: I will create a new question now to avoid the confusion, sorry about all of this.

Comment: it wont let me create a new question :/

Comment: Ok i changed the title and the post again to make it less confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) here:

```
my_str = ['A', 'B', 'C']
for i, val in enumerate(my_str):
    print ' '.join(my_str[i::-1])
```

OR, in one line as:

```
print '\n'.join(' '.join(my_str[i::-1]) for i in range(len(my_str))
```

Both of these will print:

```
A
B A
C B A
```

I am not sure whether this is what is desired. This result is based on:

> How can i make it so A will be printed and then B and A, and finally C and B and A.

Comment: Yes, but no however. I updated my code on the post. Im using a 2d list. So is there a way to do this with your code to only print the second index of that list index?

Comment: @Envurb: Please mention the input list and the desired output. Right now I do not know what you want. Also, since what you desire now is totally different from what you mention at the first place. Create a separate question and roll back this question to the previous version

Comment: that would be a good idea. Sorry about this, i've never really asked for help with my code. Il make a new question now.

Comment: it wont let me create a new question :/

Comment: Ok i changed the title and the post again to make it less confusing.